# Read data from multiple CSV files into single ffdf object

Tags: r, csv, ff, ffbase

Is it possíble to load at once data from several files into a ff data frame (ffdf)?
Lets say I have

```
big_file_part1.csv
big_file_part2.csv
big_file_part3.csv
```

I know I could load each csv file to a separate ffdf object and then ffdfrbind.fill them together. 
But that seems like an inefficient way, loading stuff twice. Is there more direct way?

Comment: How big are your files?

Comment: There are actually 27 files, one for each state. 10GB in total, but most states are small (<100MB) and 2 states are rather larger (>4GB>my RAM)

Comment: You can use the argument 'x' from read.csv.ffdf to append your data to an existing ffdf. If the different csv files have the same structure of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it (note that my source data does not have any headers).

First step - make sure all your files are in the same folder. Set your working directory to the folder.

```
#load the ffbase library
library(ffbase)

#create a vector of the files that I want to load
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

#create the first ffdf object for i = 1, this is necessary to establish the ff dataframe to append the rest
for (i in 1)
  mydata <- read.csv.ffdf(file=temp[i], header=FALSE, VERBOSE=TRUE
          , first.rows=100000, next.rows=100000, colClasses=NA)

#loop through the remaining objects
for (i in 2:length(temp))
  mydata <- read.csv.ffdf(x = mydata, file=temp[i], header=FALSE, VERBOSE=TRUE
            , first.rows=100000, next.rows=100000)
```